# How do i save modification using inplace in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

If I am deleting the column `Entity` by using this code:

`t.drop('Entity', axis=1, inplace=True)`

then the previous dataframe again comes here. so How can I save modification using `inplace=True` so that i could delete `Entity` column?

[image]

Comment: Can you also show us the DataFrame before you run the drop command? From what I see, it looks like your code is working fine. Also, please put your code, data, and desired output into the question as indented text, not pictures, so we can recreate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop both in once.

```py
rd.drop(["Entity", "Code"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your trying to drop. If you're using `axis=1`, then you're trying to drop a **column** ... in which case it looks like your code works fine (I see no column `Code` in out DataFrame output.)

If you're trying to drop **rows** based on the value of `Entity` you need to use the index of df.loc as in...

```
`df.drop(df.loc[df['columnsname']=="Entity"].index, inplace=True)`
```

or

```
`df.drop(df.loc[df['Entity']=="<some value>"].index, inplace=True)`
```

Look at this as an example...

```
from dataframefromstring import DataFrameFromString

df = DataFrameFromString() # Just loads a df for this example. Nothing to do with your code

# show the starting dataframe    
print("=== Original DF ==============")
print(df)

# Drop the column "Name"
df.drop('Name', axis=1, inplace=True)
print("=== Dropped column ==============")
print(df)

# Drop multiple columns
df.drop(['Ticket_No', "Fare"], axis=1, inplace=True)
print("=== Dropped mutiple columns ==============")
print(df)

# Drop rows based on column X having some value
df.drop(df.loc[df['Sex']=="male"].index, inplace=True)
print("=== Drop row where Column = <something> ==============")
print(df)

# Drop rows based on multiple values value
df.drop(df.loc[ (df['Sex'].isnull() ) | (df["Age"] < 42 ) ].index, inplace=True)
print("=== Drop rows based on multiple conditions ==============")
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
=== Original DF ==============
      Name     Sex   Age Ticket_No    Fare
0   Braund    male  22.0   HN07681  2500.0
1      NaN  female  42.0   HN05681  6895.0
2    peter    male   NaN    KKSN55   800.0
3      NaN    male  56.0   HN07681  2500.0
4    Daisy  female  22.0   hf55s44     NaN
5   Manson     NaN  48.0   HN07681  8564.0
6   Piston    male   NaN   HN07681  5622.0
7  Racline  female  42.0   Nh55146     NaN
8      NaN    male  22.0   HN07681  4875.0
9      NaN     NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN

=== Dropped column ==============
      Sex   Age Ticket_No    Fare
0    male  22.0   HN07681  2500.0
1  female  42.0   HN05681  6895.0
2    male   NaN    KKSN55   800.0
3    male  56.0   HN07681  2500.0
4  female  22.0   hf55s44     NaN
5     NaN  48.0   HN07681  8564.0
6    male   NaN   HN07681  5622.0
7  female  42.0   Nh55146     NaN
8    male  22.0   HN07681  4875.0
9     NaN   NaN       NaN     NaN

=== Dropped mutiple columns ==============
      Sex   Age
0    male  22.0
1  female  42.0
2    male   NaN
3    male  56.0
4  female  22.0
5     NaN  48.0
6    male   NaN
7  female  42.0
8    male  22.0
9     NaN   NaN

=== Drop row where Column = <something> ==============
      Sex   Age
1  female  42.0
4  female  22.0
5     NaN  48.0
7  female  42.0
9     NaN   NaN

=== Drop rows based on multiple conditions ==============
      Sex   Age
1  female  42.0
7  female  42.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code of `t.drop('Entity', axis=1, inplace=True)` is correct!